# IDA Pro converting to instruction functionality: how to automate.

Tags: ida, linux, ida-plugin, idapython

I am loading various files that read into IDA as binary. Once I have the GUI in front of me I am able to go through the segments and hit "c" in order to convert to instruction/code.

However, I am primarily trying to do all my ida work via linux terminal (using the command line `./idal -B input-file`). 
Is there a command line flag, or another method, to automate the generating of instructions from the binary files? Or is this something I will have to manually do every time?

Comment: For additional information: I am running IDA 6.5 on linux ubuntu 12.10. I am primarily looking at MBR files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this in IDAPython:

```
# I didn't check this code, please use carefully !This code will pass through all defined segments and will try to make code on any unexplored area
# IDAPython documentation is at https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/

import idautils
import idc

for ea in idautils.Segments():
    segend = idc.GetSegmentAttr(ea, idc.SEGATTR_END)
    start = ea
    while start < segend:
        idc.MakeCode(start)
        start = idc.FindUnexplored(start+1, idc.SEARCH_DOWN)
```

You can run it with [-S](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml) command line switch as stated in previous answer

Comment: @w s
So this seems to work when I run it via IDA GUI (going to file -> script file) and importing it that way. However, when I run it via terminal line with the -S flag. It comes out without the translated instructions. Is it something wrong with the way I am calling ida? 

`./idal -B ~/Desktop/test_binary.dump -S script.py`?

Comment: SOLVED: In order to have a command line switch recognized you need to have it appear before the file to be analysed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use specify an IDC script on the command line via the [`-S`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml) switch, with which you can try calling [`AnalyzeArea()`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/202.shtml); if that doesn't work, you can use [`MakeCode()`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/201.shtml).

Comment: Do you recommend any tutorials on IDC scripting?

Comment: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/idc/